# Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP for my copy of the site

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse

Google page speed gives an error when checking a copy of the site. Differ only ip addresses of servers, it is a full copy of the site. I don't know why this is happening. What could be the problem?

https://beerose.ru - OK
https://new.beerose.ru/ - FAIL

Comment: I have a similar problem.
Took me some time to figure out, but `NO_FCP` means "no First Contentful Paint", so the browser didn't manage to display the page.
When I actually look at the dev pages, they all redirect to nonsense.

Now to get back to your question, it's good if you can add some more specifics. Also it's usually not good practice to link directly to your sites from SO.